# wso2 esb bam server profile namespace

Tags: namespaces, wso2, wso2-bam, wso2-esb

How can we achieve namespace handling under BAM server profile stream definition (from WSO2 ESB admin console) instead of doing it under mediation flow using XPath expression?
We are suspecting this can lead to  performance problem when the input payload is large as we have to add more property mediators to extract values from payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace facility is not yet supported with BAM mediator. Property mediator is the alternative. We hope to implement that feature in BAM mediator future.

Comment: DO you see any performance overhead in case payload is big and lot of property mediator needed to parse the feed in order to send that as part of BAM stream definition ?

Comment: In WSO2 I have not come across a such blocking situation. But yes there should be a performance overhead obviously. Even after we improve the BAM mediator to work with namespaces there will be a similar amount of performance overhead cause due to large messages. Only advantage is reducing the complexity.